# How should I query google cloud datastore emulator via command line

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, gcloud, datastore

I am aware that gcloud tools can help you query variety of storage available on google cloud, but is there a way to connect to local google datastore emulator and use `gcloud sql` on it?

I tried exporting env variables as suggested

```
gcloud beta emulators datastore env-init
```

And then I tried to use following command:

```
gcloud beta sql connect project-id
```

but i get following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.sql.connect) HTTPError 403: The client is not authorized to make this request.
```

I believe there has to be a straight forward way to do this, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation doesn't show any [`gcloud`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/) command that would allow you to use sql queries with the cloud datastore emulator.

The [`gcloud beta sql`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/sql/) and [`gcloud sql`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/) commands are applicable to 
[Google Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/), which is a different cloud product than the datastore.

Answer (score 1):

This is late answer, but I want to introduce [dsio](https://github.com/nshmura/dsio): a Command line tool for Cloud Datastore.

As far as I know, there is no official tool to query to local datastore emulator. `dsio` can query to local google datastore emulator.